# User registration in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am getting the following exception

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded !!!!!!!

```
public $password;

public function generateAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    return $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}

public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
    {
        $user = new Users();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();

        if ($user->save()) {
            $this->id = $user->id;
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is that code of Users model? If that's so, why are you creating new instance of Users and calling a save again? That would create infinite recursion resulting in the error you've mentioned.

Comment: Please  help me!

Comment: PLease give us more information about this error or whata do you want to do

Comment: the very first comment has done exactly what you are asking for, i.e **HELP** please read carefully and fix your error the answer is already given

Answer (score 0):

in your User model you should canghe the function name save() with another name eg  saveUser so this is not recalled  by the inner $user->save()  that is a normal  ActiveRecord  function for save.

Calling User->save() as you are doing you produce an infinite nested  loop ..

```
  .....
  public function saveUser($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
    {
        $user = new Users();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();

        if ($user->save()) {
            $this->id = $user->id;
            return true;
        }

    }
    ...
```

In your controller Action eg:action Create  you should call  your $user->saveUser(...)

```
*/
public function actionCreateForCatone2()
{
   ....

    $user->saveUser(...);
   ...
}
```

Comment: This will definitively help with infine recursion but it's not a good way to implement it from the architectural point of view. If you aren't following principles behind used design patterns it will make code harder to understand and maintain. ActiveRecord should save itself and it's related models if needed. It shouldn't create new instance of itself. Creating and saving new instance of model will mean that the original model is not updated during save. That can lead to unexpected behavior. For example `$model->isNewRecord` will still return true after calling `saveUser()`.